# Exclude some errors from python script in linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I want to exclude some erros from log.
I'm using a Raspberry 3b+.

I use

```
main.py >> log.txt 2>&1 | grep -v "Network is unreachable"
```

My error that I don't want is

```
[tcp @ 0x19ccea0] Connection to tcp://192.168.1.32:554?timeout=0 failed: Network is unreachable
```

I can put the whole error in grep because the ip adress may change

However this error is still in my log.txt file when I run my main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pipe to `grep`, and then redirect grep's output to the file. You're redirecting all the output to the file, so nothing goes to `grep`.

```
main.py 2>&1 | grep -v "Network is unreachable" >> log.txt
```